# Lenovo Y40-70 CPU capped when under 40% of battery capacity

Tags: windows, cpu, battery, lenovo-laptop

My Lenovo Y40-70 caps its CPU at 30% frequency when it's under 40% battery while running on battery. While it's charging, it's fine and always runs at 100% speed.

I'm running Windows 10 and have to set both the min and max processor speed in Power Options to 100% for my battery plan and it has no effect. My computer came preinstalled with Windows 8.1 and I still had this issue then. I have the most updated drivers and even checked the BIOS and all the P-States look to be at max performance, yet it's still bottlenecking when running on battery.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what I can do to fix this?

Comment: This is probably a safety feature to prevent overloading the battery when the charge is low. It is entirely possible that a firmware update from Lenovo could fix this, but they may prefer it to work this way.

Comment: [This](http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/62655-35-stop-downclock-battery) seems to suggest disabling Intel SpeedStep in the BIOS as a "solution". That will stop the processor underclocking completely, even when you'd want it to such as under very light load, and will disable self-overclocking. It would waste more power, drain your battery faster and potentially loose you the peak performance that Turbo Boost provides. I wouldn't call it a good solution,  I'd just prefer to keep the battery well charged.